# Should my answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion

Regarding:

[Is compound aromatic if it has also "anti-aromatic" ring?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57678/is-compound-aromatic-if-it-has-also-anti-aromatic-ring/57679?noredirect=1#comment96463_57679)

And my answer which is upvoted 9 times (and downvoted once), is very reasonable, but  is shown to be wrong with subsequent comments and answers.

Should I remove my incorrect answer?

Comment: That is entirely up to you, but if my humble 2 cents were worth anything, I'd advise not to. Never delete anything that can be edited.

Comment: Your two cents are worth alot, but the word 'never' is not worth very much to me.  I am some worried about more junior scientists getting the idea that our hand waving simplifications can be considered as more important than the actual experiment.  This is at odds with the notion that the argument advanced is normally useful.  That molecule must have been a pain in the neck to purify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your answer, it has not been CW-ified. Yes, I know that Stack Exchange’s policy is something along the lines of ‘If you’re not comfortable with your answer becoming part of the entire blabla …’ meaning its not your answer like its your left hand, but you still gain/lose any reputation that is to be owned, get notified for comments etc.

Before I get to what I suggest you can do, I’m going to say that I was one of the people who upvoted the answer, simply not knowing that a crystal structure exists, because it is in line with ‘conventional wisdom’ as someone put it. Since that was shown to be wrong by the experiment, I must readjust what I think is right and wrong. As such, I have retracted my upvote (thankfully, your edit unlocked the post) for now. I didn’t downvote, because it still shows a good thing to know. (However, remember that how people use votes is entirely their discreetion so others may or may not do what I did.)

Concerning the answer’s future, you have two general option:

- Admit that you thought wrongly, delete it and collect the *Disciplined* badge.
- Admit that you thought wrongly. Edit the answer to read something along the lines of ‘conventional theory would tell us this because of these reasons and foo. However, the experiment showed that that is wrong in this case, and it is actually that for those reasons and bar.’ And continue collecting upvotes.
- Be a sly old fox and combine the two options: Delete the answer first to get *disciplined*, then edit and undelete it according to the second bullet point and profit twice.

It’s up to you what you prefer.